# Python: how to send a post request to a server when using specific ports

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to send a post request to a server, code is as follows:

```
import requests    
response = requests.post('https://example.com:9121',
    data=reg_data.encode('utf-8'),
    headers=headers, params=params, verify=False)
```

the response is:

```
[Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

but when delete the specified port, like:

```
response = requests.post('https://example.com',
    data=reg_data.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers, params=params, verify=False)
```

the response is:

```
Response [200]
```

I want to know why I can't send post to the url with specified ports while that is what I need. I can handle it in java Application, I don't know how to handle it in Python.

Comment: This is not a Python problem; this is a problem with the server listening on port 9121.

Comment: You can see that port numbers have nothing to do with it by specifying the default HTTPS port number for your second URL:  `'https://example.com:443'`.

Comment: The SSL module is telling you that the server listening on port 9121 did not provide a valid SSL response. My guess is that the service on 9121 doesn't use SSL at all, and is giving a plain HTTP response. Try using `http://example.com:9121` instead of `https://example.com:9121`.

Comment: If I do not use '9121', but other random numbers like '456', the response is:('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')). And my program need that '9121'. is that I need to add some certificate file since the connection is SSL